# How to sort strings in a arbitrary or given order in Mongo Aggregation Pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation pipeline that returns 20 tuples with known _id's:

```
[ { _id: 'AA', value: 5 },
  { _id: 'CD', value: 2 },
```

How to create a pipeline stage to order them in an arbitrary order?

For example 'CD', 'AA', 'EF', 'BC'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query1

- this is for random order
- add a temp field with a random value
- sort by it
- unset the temp field

*i don't know if this is the optimal way to do it, but it works

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6323d90478a49d87828514b4)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"rand": {"$rand": {}}}},
 {"$sort": {"rand": 1}},
 {"$unset": ["rand"]}])
```

Query2

- this in to apply a specific order for example "CD then AA etc"
- add a new field that contains the index of the `_id` from the array that defines the order
- sort by it
- unset it

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6324011c78a49d87828514b7)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"key": {"$indexOfArray": [["CD", "AA"], "$_id"]}}},
 {"$sort": {"key": 1}},
 {"$unset": ["key"]}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Takis' answer.

```
         { '$addFields': {
            'order': { '$indexOfArray': [ ['CD', 'AA', 'EF', 'BC'...], '$_id' ] }}},
         { '$sort': { 'order': 1 }}]
```